# RegEx expression to replace delimiters separating words

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, I'd like to replace a PHP array variable with a function call in the following way:

```
$trad['newsletter']['title']['something'];
$trad['newsletter']['placeholder'];
$trad['buttons']['send']['text']['small'];
```

The result would be:

```
lang('newsletter.title.something');
lang('newsletter.placeholder');
lang('buttons.send.text.small');
```

I have tried with the expression

```
\$trad\s?\[(.+('\]\[').+)\]
```

but only captures the last occurrence of `']['`

Comment: Try in two steps, 1) `\$trad\['(.*)']` => `lang('$1')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKLMh0/3)) and 2) `(?:\G(?!\A)|lang\().*?\K']\['` => `.` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKLMh0/4))

Comment: Please drop a comment if the solution works for you.

Comment: Hi! I have tried out your solution but unfortunately, PhpStorm Find engine is made in Java that does not recognize \K. I have tried another approach in two steps. First for expressions with three keys with `\$trad\s?\['([\w\-]+)']\['([\w\-]+)']\['([\w\-]+)'\]([^\[])` and then second step `\$trad\s?\['([\w\-]+)']\['([\w\-]+)'\]([^\[])` for two-keyed expresions.

Comment: You do not need `\K` if your engine does not support it. Use `(\G(?!\A)|lang\()(.*?)']\['` and replace with `$1$2.`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKLMh0/5).

Comment: That also worked, indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step for three keyed expressions: `\$trad\s?\['([\w\-]+)']\['([\w\-]+)']\['([\w\-]+)'\]([^\[])` replace with `lang('$1.$2.$3)$4`.
Second step for two keyed expressions: `\$trad\s?\['([\w\-]+)']\['([\w\-]+)'\]([^\[])` replaced with `lang('$1.$2')$3`. I optimized the code to avoid more than 3 keys.